# How to use directory paths stored in property file in ANT dirset or fileset?

Tags: ant, properties, build, dirset

I need to store some directory paths in property files for ant. So I have file that contains for example:

```
plugins.system=plugins\\whatever
plugins.content=plugins\\example

this.is.fine=plugins
this.also.does.not.work=plugins/example
```

The problem is, that dirset or fileset does not find the directory. I belive, that it's due escaping. When I set property directly in build.xml without double slashes it works fine. Is there any way how to "unescape" properties when I load them?

Thank you for answer.

Comment: I recommend always using forward slashes to represent path separators. Ant is smart enough to convert them into the separator used by the OS. The paths are likely being evaluated relative to the `basedir` defined as an attribute of the `<project>` element. Please post some code showing how `basedir` is set, how you read the properties from the file, and how you attempt to use the relative paths.

Comment: Thanks. I use / instead of \\ now, but it works for both ways. I had problem when I was iterating list created by propertyselector, so there has not been any problem with slashes. Thanks for crearing how to work with slashes anyway.